# Infinite QGraphicsView::resizeEvent calls

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qlayout, qevent

I have a custom layout BoardLayout, which inherits QLayout. It is written in analogy to BorderLayout example (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-borderlayout-example.html), with a following `setGeometry()` method:

```
void BoardLayout::setGeometry(const QRect &rect)
{
    QLayout::setGeometry(rect);
    int d = qMin(rect.width() - 175, rect.height() - 100);
    for (auto e : list) {
        if (e->position == Board) {
            e->item->setGeometry({50, 50, d, d});
        }
    }
}
```

It also has an altered `BoardLayout::calculateSize` method, but since the widget it is applied on is a `centralWidget` of a window, it probably does not matter; this method is also not called in the problematic part of runtime).

I set this layout for a window, and added to it (in the position of `Board`) an instance of a `BoardView` class, (`BoardView` inherits `QGraphicsView`):

```
auto lt = new BoardLayout();
setLayout(lt);
    
board_view_ = new BoardView(config_, this);
lt->addWidget(board_view_, BoardLayout::Board);
```

I did not add any other objects into the layout, so it could maybe be written simpler, but the structure and the API of `BoardLayout` are kept the same to maintain the analogy with the working example.

This `BoardView` class has an overriden method `resizeEvent`, in order to keep the inside objects to occupy all the space of the viewport by changing scale each time it is resized:

```
void BoardView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {
    if (event->oldSize().width() == -1) {
        qreal k = (qreal)qMin(width(), height()) / ((config_->scene_cell_size + 4) * config_->board_size);
        scale(k, k);
    }
    else {
        qreal prev_w = event->oldSize().width(), prev_h = event->oldSize().height();
        qreal w = event->size().width(), h = event->size().height();
        qreal k = qMin(w, h) / qMin(prev_w, prev_h);
        scale(k, k);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, in such a setup, when I start the app, `BoardView::resizeEvent` is called non-stop with a pair of different `QSize`'s, one after another, even though the window (and hence the containing widget, that has the `BoardLayout` as a layout) is not being resized.
During this, `BoardLayout::setGeometry` is not called, so I don't get where this resize events could come from.

Also, if I delete `scale(k, k);` from `BoardView::resizeEvent` it works normally as expected (resize events only come after resizing the window, triggered by `e->item->setGeometry` in `BoardLayout::setGeometry`).

Same thing happens if I change the layout to one of the standard ones, or choose some different rectangles for `e->item->setGeometry({50, 50, d, d});`.

So, I would be grateful if someone could explain what is wrong with this architecture, and how are the unnecessary `resizeEvents` triggered.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the events were issued by two `QScrollBar`s that appear when viewport is too small for the scene. However it only happens when objects are on the edge between fitting and not fitting into the scene and the scrollbars actually appear and disappear and something complicated happens in the event cycle that I cannot understand because it is hard to find the docs on what happens and when.

However, if we change the scaling coefficient so that scrollbars would either always appear, or always not, everything works fine. It may be that it is not a correct solution and only works in practice because some events always get processed fast enough, which is not guaranteed.